# Transform response to plain-text using wso2 esb 4.0.6

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm new to web-service and somehow I have created a simple web-service over http/https using wso2 esb 4.0.6. Now my requirement is to remove the tag from response i.e. i need plain text in response, below code snippets will give u a brief idea of my requirement.

```
<case regex="POST">
   <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
       <enrich>
     <source type="inline" clone="true">
         <success xmlns="">Your request for subscription is being processed.</success>
     </source>
     <target type="body"/>
    </enrich>
     <header name="To" action="remove"/>
      <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
      <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <property name="ContentType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
</case>
```

I'm able to get the below response `<success>Your request for subscription is being processed.</success>`

I just want to remove the `<success> </success>` tags from the response.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

May be this is bit late, but I too have came across this recently, and here's how you can make it work.

1. Make sure in ESB/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml plainTextFormatter is enabled.
2. In your proxy service set 'messageType' property as shown below
3. Add a payload text element. Please refer to the out sequence of the sample proxy service given below

> ```
> <outSequence>
>          <payloadFactory>
>             <format>
>                <ms11:text xmlns:ms11="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$1</ms11:text>
>             </format>
>             <args>
>                <arg xmlns:ns="http://www.wso2.org/types" expression="$body/ns:greetResponse/return/text()"/>
>             </args>
>          </payloadFactory>
>          <property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
>          <log level="full"/>
>          <send/>
>       </outSequence>
> ```

In this scenario my response from the backend service (HelloService) is as follows.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"> 
  <soapenv:Body> 
    <ns:greetResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.wso2.org/types"> 
      <return>Hello World, Test !!!</return> 
   </ns:greetResponse> 
 </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

See below the request and response for the GET request using curl command

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8280/services/TestProxy/greet?name=Test" -v 
* About to connect() to localhost port 8280 (#0) 
* Trying 127.0.0.1... connected 
> GET /services/TestProxy/greet?name=Test HTTP/1.1 
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3 
> Host: localhost:8280 
> Accept: */* 
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 
< Server: WSO2 Carbon Server 
< Vary: Accept-Encoding 
< Date: Wed, 25 Sep 2013 06:08:21 GMT 
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact 
* Closing connection #0 
Hello World, Test !!!
```

Thanks
Sajith

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the full envelope as inline source.
Eg:

```
 <inSequence>
         <enrich>
            <source type="inline" clone="true">
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">                        
                  <soapenv:Body>     Your request for subscription is being processed.   </soapenv:Body>               
               </soapenv:Envelope>
            </source>
            <target type="envelope"/>
         </enrich>
         <header name="To" action="remove"/>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="Content-Type" value="text/plain" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've tried your above snippet, but I'm not getting anything in the response.                                                                                                                                                                                                   Please suggest some way to get the only plain text as response.

Comment: For the above you will get response like; <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">                        
                  <soapenv:Body>     Your request for subscription is being processed.   </soapenv:Body>               
               </soapenv:Envelope>   what do u mean by not getting anything above? then your configuration is worng

Comment: apologies for misunderstanding,I've tested other web-service with the same config. and they are working fine, actually after invoking this web-service, I'm getting **<success details="empty response"/>** as a response.I just need **Your request for subscription is being processed.** as the response i.e without any success tags.

Comment: I've tried the above problem using Curl & at console I'm getting the following outcome
`> GET /services/SampleProxy?param=123456789 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.5 (i586-pc-mingw32msvc) libcurl/7.19.5 zlib/1.2.3
> Host: myhost:8280
> Accept: */*
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Host: localhost:8280
< RESPONSE: true
< Content-Type: text/plain
--
< Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
--
--
* Connection #0 to host myhost left intact
* Closing connection #0`

In logs I'm getting the required response i.e
**<soapenv:Body>Your request for subscription is being processed.</soapenv:Body>**
plz suggest.Thnx in adv